# Report generated is empty, does not show the scenarios

Tags: serenity-js

I have been running npm test with the latest serenity-cli.jar and suddenly now the report is generated but it does not have any scenarios shown here.
Is this because of the latest jar file? does anyone else face this issue? also is there a way i can downgrade as it always picks up the latest build.

Comment: it always expects to be the latest jar file, if not gives error "Error: Unable to access jarfile /node_modules/serenity-cli/.cache/serenity-cli-1.2.4-all.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the folder under `target/site/serenity` and rerun test pretest and report. It usually helps me with reporting issues.

Comment: I did try this but it does not help, it says 0 scenarios are automated, even though when i have. I have the same issue as reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266868/serenity-report-empty-0-test-scenarios , there is no answer for this question.